# Multiple mysqli_query statements in a single php IF statement not working

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have the following code...

```
for ($n = 0, $t = count($_POST['PMComments']); $n < $t; $n++) {
$UpdateValue             = $_POST['Update'][$n];
$PMCommentsValue         = $_POST['PMComments'][$n];
$PMMRecommendationsValue = $_POST['PMMRecommendations'][$n];
$OutcomeValue            = $_POST['Outcome'][$n];
$LineID                  = $_POST['LineID'][$n];

$sqlUPDATE = "UPDATE report SET PMComments = '$PMCommentsValue' , PMMRecommendations = '$PMMRecommendationsValue' , Outcome = '$OutcomeValue' WHERE LineID = $LineID ;";
echo $sqlUPDATE . "<br>";  //this echos back the entire SQL entry that will be made
$doUPDATE = mysqli_query($con, $sqlUPDATE);
if (!$doUPDATE) {
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error());
}

if ($OutcomeValue <> 'null') {                  

$sqlMOVE = "INSERT INTO results SELECT * FROM report WHERE LineID = $LineID ; DELETE FROM report where LineID = $LineID ;";
echo $sqlMOVE ;
$doMOVE = mysqli_query($con, $sqlMOVE);
  if (!$doMove) {
  die('SQL Move didnt work: ' . mysqli_error());
  }  
}  

}
```

The first part of the code works just fine - I have a few columns and some dropdowns in a table that is populated from a mySQL database.  When I change a field and hit enter, (or submit), it executes this for all visible rows in the table.  The first part works: `$doUPDATE` , it updates my database just fine.  However, the second part is not working - I keep running into my `die('SQL MOVE didnt work);`

What I am trying to do here is update each row whenever a change is made, (check.), then, as `$n` is cycling from 0 to `$t`, in the event an `$OutcomeValue` is NOT null, move that specific row out of the current database and into another.

Is the reason why this is not working because I am trying to concurrently run two mySQLi statements back to back?  Do I need some sort of break in between the two that I'm not putting in?  The actual query that it generates, (from the `echo $sqlMOVE ;` is fine syntax-wise... I can run it without error manually in an SQL query window, just not in this nested if statement.

Comment: Just noticed that you are using a multiple query for your $sqlMove. You might want to have a look at the mulit statement: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: You cannot execute 2 queries using `mysqli_query()` -> `"INSERT INTO results SELECT * FROM report WHERE LineID = $LineID ; DELETE FROM report where LineID = $LineID ;"`. You either need to do 2 `mysqli_query()` OR use `mysqli_multi_query()`

Comment: note: you are missing the connection - `$con` - in `mysqli_error()` -> `die('SQL Move didnt work: ' . mysqli_error($con));`

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the tips everyone.  I messed around with the multi_query for a few hours, trying both the procedural and OO approaches and I couldn't get it to execute.  I ended up going with what @Sean recommended above and put this into two separate queries, which worked fine.

```
if ($OutcomeValue <> 'null') {                  

  $sqlMOVE  = "INSERT INTO results SELECT * FROM report WHERE LineID = $LineID ;" ;
  $sqlDELETE = "DELETE FROM report where LineID = $LineID ;" ;
  $doMOVE = mysqli_query($con, $sqlMOVE);
  if (!$doMOVE) 
    {
      die('Could not MOVE data: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
  $doDELETE = mysqli_query($con, $sqlDELETE);
  if (!$doDELETE) 
    {
      die('Could not DELETE data: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    } 
}
```

and this was successful!  Thanks!